# Use geom_boxplot with variable of type double on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data set looks like the following:

```
df = tibble (
    gender = rep(c("fem","mal"),each=10),
    C = rep(rep(c(0,1), each=5),2),
    r = rep(c(0,1,2,3,4),4),
    value = rnorm(n = 20,mean = 5,sd = 1)
)
```

And I have a problem when plotting it with:

```
df %>% ggplot() + geom_boxplot(aes(x=C,y=value,fill=gender))
```

Because boxplots are not separated by values of my variable C, I presume because it is of type double. In fact, if I write `aes(x=factor(C), ...)` the problem disappear.

I ask because I'm wondering if I can keep this variable as double in the aesthetic and still separate the boxplots by their value. This approach is more convenient in order to later use `scale_x_continuous` with custom breaks.

Comment: The problem with `scale_x_discrete` is that for a wider range of values of my variable `x=C` if I set `breaks=c(0.0,0.5,1.0)` for instance, it does not get the full range (in fact it only shows "0.5" in the x-axis). Perhaps it is more natural to solve this problem in the very same scale the original variable is supposed to be

Comment: I was referring there in the comment to a "wider range of values of my variable `x=C`". Data in the original post is aimed to reproduce the problem, but the real data of course have more values, including values for the variable in that axis.

Comment: You can add `group = interaction(gender, C)` to your `aes`

Comment: @kath Actually this does work as expected, though I don't know what is doing exactly. If you can elaborate it into an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a group to your aesthetics solves the problem. I added a `scale_x_continuous` - call to demonstrate that this works and also show how you might want to manipulate the width of your boxplots with `width` and `position_dodge`.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = C, y = value, fill = gender, group = interaction(gender, C)), 
               position = position_dodge(0.1), width = 0.1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2))
```

[image]

What is `interaction(gender, C)` and why does it work? 
`interaction` creates a special factor variable by pasting the values of gender and C together. We can see how it works, when providing it as `fill`-aesthetic:

```
ggplot(my.df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = C, y = value, fill = interaction(gender, C)))
```

[image]

When it is added as a `group`-aesthetic it tells ggplot which boxplot-groups you'd like to have.